# In simplifying $\sqrt{\frac{(x^2 +x +3)^2}{(1-2q)^2}}$ to $\frac{x^2 +x +3}{|1-2q|}$, why use the absolute value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have seen in a question

$$\sqrt{\frac{(x^2 +x +3)^2}{(1-2q)^2}}$$ was given to be
$$\frac{x^2 +x +3}{|1-2q|}$$

Why was absolute value given to $1-2q$?

Comment: Typically $\sqrt{x}$ refers to the positive square root of $x$.

Comment: (In the real numbers ...) Since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ gives the non-negative square root, technically we *always* use the absolute value: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$. (Sometimes, that equality is even used as the *definition* of absolute value.) So, the *better* question is: *Why **wasn't** the absolute value used in the numerator?* Well, we can leave the absolute value off of an expression if we know it never becomes negative. So, it must be that $x^2+x+3$ is never negative (for real $x$); can you show why?

Comment: but in the next question it was given x^2 -x +3 but there too absolute value as omitted why?

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: @Shashaank It's also true that $x^2 - x + 3 \ge 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, so absolute values are not necessary. Just check that the discriminant is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by definition you have that:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{(x^2 +x +3)^2}{(1-2q)^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{(x^2 +x +3)^2}}{\sqrt{(1-2q)^2}}
$$

and you got that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\  \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

so you get that:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{(x^2 +x +3)^2}}{\sqrt{(1-2q)^2}} = \frac{|(x^2 +x +3)|}{|(1-2q)|}
$$

Clearly $x^2 \geq 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, and in particular you have that $x^2 \geq x $ while $|x| > 1$, if $x \in [-1,1]$ you can easily see that $ x^2 + x < 3$  so you have that $x^2+x+3$ is always greater than 0 so you can get rid of $|.|$ (as well when you consider $x^2-x+3$)

Now if you have $q > 0$ you can see that $1-2q$ is not necessarily positive, so you need to use your absolute value.

If you still have doubts I suggest you to graph the functions and watch that both $x^2-x+3$ and $x^2+x+3$ are positive in all its codomain! :)